# Why can't I give array elements a value outside of a method in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, arrays, initialization, variable-declaration

Before my `onCreate()` method I can easily declare and initialise data types like `int` with the code

```
int number = 2;
```

however if I want to do this with an array, using code such as

```
float[] array = new float[2];
array[0] = 1;
```

the second line gives me an error. Why is this? Is there a way of initialising this array before the `onCreate()` method like I can do with other data types?

Comment: Well you could use `float[] array = { 1f, 0f };` instead... but basically, you can't have regular statements directly at the class level - only declarations and initializer blocks.

Answer (score 1):

An Android Activity is just a normal class.
There, regular statements can only be executed in:

methods

```
void x(){
    // do something nice here
}
```

instance contructors (that would be bad practise)

```
public class A {

    public A() {
       // you also could some stuff here
    }
}
```

"class constructors" / static blocks:

```
static {
    // here you can also do something
}
```

last possebility to set values to your array is on defining it:

```
float[] myArray = { 1f; 2f;};
```

I hope this can help you